# Regex Character Set [^\\w\\d\\s\\&] does not work

Tags: java, regex

I've searched several posts that might provide the answer I need, but I could not find one.

I wonder why this regex:

```
Pattern.compile("[^\\w\\s\\d\\&]")
```

Would not work properly on a String like:

```
"AE&E randomstr§%%%ing b§)$§$/bla & some text"
```

The outcome would be (as tested):

```
"AE E randomstring blabla some text"
```

Although I specifically excluded the ampersand. Does the previous tokens overrule it? Can anyone clarify the logic behind this?

My code:

```
    String str = "AE&E randomstr§%%%ing b45747bla & some text";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^\\w\\s\\d\\&]");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    str = StringUtils.normalizeSpace(matcher.replaceAll(" "));
```

Comment: Why have you escaped & ?

Comment: I was desperate. It would'nt work unescaped either though...

Comment: ... cut that. I SWEAR I tried it both ways at least 5 times. Now it just... works... can't believe it...

Comment: Can you just say what you would like to achieve? Do you want to replace all non-word characters with spaces?

Comment: @detunized
I want to replace all characters not \w, \s or \d with spaces EXCEPT the ampersand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to appologize. I swear I tried it unescaped and escaped and it seems to NOT work. Roddy of the Frozen Peas made me try once more, and MAGICALLY now the script does what it should.

Thanks to the commenters,

-solved!

working code:

```
String str = "AE&E randomstr§%%%ing b45747bla & some text";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^\\w\\s\\d&]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
str = StringUtils.normalizeSpace(matcher.replaceAll(" "));
```

Answer (score 1):

It works properly.
The ampersand is replaced, since you excluded it from **allowed** characters.

Comment: I am sorry, but your answer is not right. The matching group excludes the ampersand. And the replace function replaces everything in the matching group with spaces. Since the matching group is all BUT ampersand, etc... , it should not be replaced.